# Can anyone explain how the code worked below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new and am currently learning python. The code below is an average height calculator. I would appreciate it a ton if someone can explain to me how

```
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
  student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])
```

works, and how the variables total_height and number_of_students acted like the functions sum and len? Thank you to anyone who will answer, it will help my learning a lot!

```
### I don't understand the code below ###
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
  student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])

total_height = 0
for height in student_heights:
  total_height += height
print(f"total height = {total_height}")

number_of_students = 0
for student in student_heights:
  number_of_students += 1
print(f"number of students = {number_of_students}")
### I don't understand the code above ###
  
average_height = round(total_height / number_of_students)
print(average_height)
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @Barmar he clearly commented it out !

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a tutorial on Python `for` loops.

Comment: It loops each entry in `student_heights` and converts it to its integer format using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int), as `split()`-ing values from `input()` will return you string-typed variables which can't/shouldn't be used for arithmetic operations.

Comment: Seems like using a `for` loop to count the students is the hard way when you could just use `number_of_students = len(student_heights)`.

Comment: @Programmer I mean more specific than that. Do they not understand `range(0, len(student_heights))`, `for n in ...`, `int(student_heights[n])`?

Comment: @FredLarson I think they know that, they asked how this acts like `len()`.

Comment: @Barmar: Oh, maybe.

Comment: @Franccesca, please revisit for-loop and how to use lists in python. The question you have are basics and as Barmar mentioned, if you review fundamentals around lists and for-loop, you can address all these questions. Also, you don't need so many lines to get to some of the answers. For ex: len(student_height) will give you # of students, sum(student_height) will give you total height of students, etc. A list comprehension can just convert all values in a list to integers or a use of map will do.

Comment: `student_height_ints = list(map(int, student_heights))` see if you understand this. This code should help you convert all strings in the student_heights list to integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't how Stack Overflow is meant to be used, so you may receive a few downvotes. However, I quite enjoy reading through code and helping others so here we go!

```
    student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
    for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
      student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])
```

This bit of code creates a list of heights from whatever was inputted. As the input is a string, we then convert each height to an integer and store it back in the list. (If you enter something that is not an integer, this will break and give you an error). The `.split()` splits the input at any whitespace, so for example entering "50 60 42" will be split into a list of "50", "60" and "42". The loop would then convert this to a list of 50, 60 and 42 - note the lack of quotes as these are now integers.

```
    total_height = 0
    for height in student_heights:
      total_height += height
    print(f"total height = {total_height}")
```

This bit loops through each of the heights that we have just converted to integers and adds them up, so total_height is equal to the sum of each value in the list. The `+=` means "this value +" - so `total_height += height` is the same as `total_height = total_height + height`. If we had a list of 50, 60 and 42 then we could step through the code as follows:

```
    First iteration: total_height = 0, height = 50
    total_height = total_height + height
    total_height = 0 + 50
    total_height = 50
    
    Second iteration: total_height = 50, height = 60
    total_height = total_height + height
    total_height = 50 + 60
    total_height = 110
    
    Third iteration: total_height = 110, height = 42
    total_height = total_height + height
    total_height = 110 + 42
    total_height = 152
```

Feel free to comment if you don't get this bit!

```
    number_of_students = 0
    for student in student_heights:
      number_of_students += 1
    print(f"number of students = {number_of_students}")
```

This bit again loops through each of the heights in the list, but this time counts how many there are - the result of this is the same as doing `len(student_heights)`. Using the same example as before (50, 60, 42):

```
    First iteration: num_students = 0, student = 50
    num_students = num_students + 1
    num_students = 0 + 1
    num_students = 1

    Second iteraation: num_students = 1, student = 60
    num_students = num_students + 1
    num_students = 1 + 1
    num_students = 2
    
    Third iteration: num_students = 2, student = 42
    num_students = num_students + 1
    num_students = 2 + 1
    num_students = 3
```

Again, let me know if anything here doesn't make sense either!

```
    average_height = round(total_height / number_of_students)
    print(average_height)
```

Now that we've added all the heights together, and counted how many students we have, we can divide these numbers and then round them to give us a nicer number. Using our examples before (for a list of 60,50,42):

```
    average_height = round(total_height / number_of_students)
    average_height = round(152 / 3)
    average_height = round(50.66666666666666666666666)
    average_height = 51
```

In this case, the program outputs 51.

Answer (score 2):

```py
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
for n in range(0, len(student_heights)):
  student_heights[n] = int(student_heights[n])
```

gets a string of numbers separated by spaces from the user, splits the string at whitespaces, and converts each of the resulting strings to a number.

```py
total_height = 0
for height in student_heights:
  total_height += height
print(f"total height = {total_height}")
```

sums the heights of all students and prints the total height

```py
number_of_students = 0
for student in student_heights:
  number_of_students += 1
print(f"number of students = {number_of_students}")
```

counts how much students there are, and prints the number.

Part 2 can be replaced with

```py
total_height = sum(student_heights)
print(f"total height = {total_height}")
```

and Part 3 can be replaced with

```py
number_of_students = len(student_heights)
print(f"number of students = {number_of_students}")
```

But in fact, this way you do not need a intermediate variable, you can just print the values directly. Part 2 + 3:

```py
print(f"total height = {sum(student_heights)}")
print(f"number of students = {len(student_heights)}")
```